# Python schedule module not working in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7

I am running python 2.7.12 and 3.5.2

I have used `pip install schedule` to install the schedule module. It is meant to be compatible with both Python 2 and 3.

When i run a script using Python 2 the schedule module works fine, however when I run the same script  with Python 3 it says **No module named schedule**

Path to schedule module is ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages

Is there are seperate schedule package for python 3 ? or how can I get Python 3 to use the installed package.

Comment: You need to install the package in Python 3 too. Something like `pip3 install schedule` should work

Comment: thanks andrea ! installed pip3 and schedule and all working now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure your package is installed in Python 3.5.2

For example, if you use virtualenv

```
virtualenv -p python3 venv
source venv/bin/activate
pip install schedule
pip freeze
```

Check yourself

P.s. new features of Python 3.5 can help your use async/await expressions and asyncio module and event loops. Your Python already contains a scheduler=) But it's just to know

Comment: and if you are using Python3 without virtualenv then make 'pip3 install schedule' of course

Comment: and check "pip3 freeze"

Comment: thanks for the reply @oleg-korobov im new to Python so haven't started using environments yet. Is using virtualenv the same idea as using annaconda to package modules in an evironment ? Im trying to work out what the difference/benefit of using either virtualenv/annaconda/Docker

Comment: In brief, Anaconda is ready set of libraries like scipy and so on. It's very convenient for Windows users. Anaconda just makes new virtualenv with ready packages.
Using just virtualenv is good practice. You  should not garbage your system Python because different projects needs different libraries with different versions

Comment: Docker is like virtual enviroment in your OS=) 
Something like isolated OS in your OS=) Cool thing

Comment: thank you my friend that clears things up. Looks like I need to read up and start using virtualenv ! thanks again my friend

Answer (score 2):

Run the following command to install `schedule`  module.

```
pip3 install scheaadule
```

Run `pip3 freezze` to update requirement.txt.
this is good Now